# Tips on understanding one-bond J couplings in NMR

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I have just started a spectroscopy course in nuclear magnetic resonance, which I have loved thus far, but have been extremely puzzled regarding <sup>1</sup>J coupling constants.

I was wondering if any of you had tips to further understand <sup>1</sup>J coupling constants as a whole. For example, I'm confused about bonding between two of the same atoms (<sup>119</sup>Sn-<sup>119</sup>Sn) and between those with different spins (<sup>14</sup>N-<sup>15</sup>N), and how it would relate to the intensity on a spectrum.

I have talked to my professor about it; however, he is unclear about these concepts specifically, I would appreciate any help on this subject :)

Comment: Do you have a textbook, or a more specific question? You might look at the further reading list on this site: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/resources-for-learning-chemistry

Comment: Usually with couplings it is the *splitting* pattern that is a concern. You are asking about peak intensities, and those depend on the nucleus too of course, and can depend on the extent of splitting for various reasons. Perhaps you can be more clear about what you are wondering about (splitting patterns and intensity of couplings versus peak intensities).

Comment: One-bond couplings are not any different from any other couplings. There’s nothing special about how many bonds the coupling occurs over (except for the *magnitude* of the coupling, but that’s just a number which kind of falls from the sky anyway). Your question about *same/different nuclides* suggests to me that the confusion is not about one-bond couplings per se, but rather about couplings between equivalent or inequivalent nuclei. But you need to explain your question better, preferably with one or more example compounds.

Comment: (… In particular, if you are puzzled by some specific question or problem that was given to you, then just put that question here.)